# Spark SQL: How to append new row to dataframe table (from another table)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark SQL with dataframes. I have an input dataframe, and I would like to append (or insert) its rows to a larger dataframe that has more columns. How would I do that?

If this were SQL, I would use `INSERT INTO OUTPUT SELECT ... FROM INPUT`, but I don't know how to do that with Spark SQL.

For concreteness:

```
var input = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(
        (10L, "Joe Doe", 34),
        (11L, "Jane Doe", 31),
        (12L, "Alice Jones", 25)
        )).toDF("id", "name", "age")

var output = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(
        (0L, "Jack Smith", 41, "yes", 1459204800L),
        (1L, "Jane Jones", 22, "no", 1459294200L),
        (2L, "Alice Smith", 31, "", 1459595700L)
        )).toDF("id", "name", "age", "init", "ts")


scala> input.show()
+---+-----------+---+
| id|       name|age|
+---+-----------+---+
| 10|    Joe Doe| 34|
| 11|   Jane Doe| 31|
| 12|Alice Jones| 25|
+---+-----------+---+

scala> input.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- age: integer (nullable = false)


scala> output.show()
+---+-----------+---+----+----------+
| id|       name|age|init|        ts|
+---+-----------+---+----+----------+
|  0| Jack Smith| 41| yes|1459204800|
|  1| Jane Jones| 22|  no|1459294200|
|  2|Alice Smith| 31|    |1459595700|
+---+-----------+---+----+----------+

scala> output.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- age: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- init: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ts: long (nullable = false)
```

I would like to append all the rows of `input` to the end of `output`. At the same time, I would like to set the `output` column of `init` to be an empty string `''` and the `ts` column to be the current timestamp, e.g. 1461883875L.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: By the way, for distributed data there is no "start" nor "end", you shall forget of indexes. Besides, using `var`s in Scala is known as a bad practice. What is the default value for `ts` in the schema you show that it is not nullable

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Spark `DataFrames` are immutable so it is not possible to append / insert rows. Instead you can just add missing columns and use `UNION ALL`:

```
output.unionAll(input.select($"*", lit(""), current_timestamp.cast("long")))
```

Comment: This is fantastic. Thank you.

Comment: Lovely, I was going to answer `output.unionAll(input.select(input.columns.map(col) ++ List(lit("").as("init"), lit(0L).as("ts")) :_*)).show`, but your answer is obviously better

Comment: I was also considering: `var input2 = input.withColumn("init", lit(null:String)).withColumn("ts", current_timestamp.cast("long"))` and then doing unionAll()

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem matching to your SQL-Question:

I wanted to append a dataframe to an existing hive table, which is also larger (more columns). To keep your example: `output` is my existing table and `input` could be the dataframe. My solution uses simply SQL and for the sake of completeness I want to provide it:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode

var input = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
        (10L, "Joe Doe", 34),
        (11L, "Jane Doe", 31),
        (12L, "Alice Jones", 25)
        )).toDF("id", "name", "age")

//--> just for a running example: In my case the table already exists
var output = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
        (0L, "Jack Smith", 41, "yes", 1459204800L),
        (1L, "Jane Jones", 22, "no", 1459294200L),
        (2L, "Alice Smith", 31, "", 1459595700L)
        )).toDF("id", "name", "age", "init", "ts")

output.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable("appendTest");
//<--

input.createOrReplaceTempView("inputTable");

spark.sql("INSERT INTO TABLE appendTest SELECT id, name, age, null, null FROM inputTable");
val df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM appendTest")
df.show()
```

which outputs:

```
+---+-----------+---+----+----------+
| id|       name|age|init|        ts|
+---+-----------+---+----+----------+
|  0| Jack Smith| 41| yes|1459204800|
|  1| Jane Jones| 22|  no|1459294200|
|  2|Alice Smith| 31|    |1459595700|
| 12|Alice Jones| 25|null|      null|
| 11|   Jane Doe| 31|null|      null|
| 10|    Joe Doe| 34|null|      null|
+---+-----------+---+----+----------+
```

If you may have the problem, that you don't know how much fields are missing, you could use a `diff` like

```
val missingFields = output.schema.toSet.diff(input.schema.toSet)
```

and then (in bad pseudo code)

```
val sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO TABLE appendTest SELECT " + commaSeparatedColumnNames + commaSeparatedNullsForEachMissingField + " FROM inputTable"
```

Hope to help people with future problems like that!

P.S.: In your special case (current timestamp + empty field for init) you could even use

```
spark.sql("INSERT INTO TABLE appendTest SELECT id, name, age, '' as init, current_timestamp as ts FROM inputTable");
```

which results in

```
+---+-----------+---+----+----------+
| id|       name|age|init|        ts|
+---+-----------+---+----+----------+
|  0| Jack Smith| 41| yes|1459204800|
|  1| Jane Jones| 22|  no|1459294200|
|  2|Alice Smith| 31|    |1459595700|
| 12|Alice Jones| 25|    |1521128513|
| 11|   Jane Doe| 31|    |1521128513|
| 10|    Joe Doe| 34|    |1521128513|
+---+-----------+---+----+----------+
```

Comment: Is there a way without using SQL

Answer (score 0):

**How to copy duplicate rows or data from dataframes using spark sql**

**First create table of exixting data using spark scala**

`spark.sql("CREATE TABLE first USING DELTA LOCATION 'path of input file'")`

Now Insert the data into the table in what ever way you want to modify the query
`spark.sql("insert into first select * from first limit 1")`
or with where condition

Now u will have duplicate data in table 'first'