# Add a row at the beginning for existing spark dataset

Tags: apache-spark

Is there a way to add a new ROW to an existing dataset in spark. I know that `withColumn` can help in adding a new column .But I want a new row to my dataset.

existing dataset:

```
    Dataset<String> uniqData = bookData.mapPartitions(new calculator(), Encoders.STRING());
```

uniqData contains elements like:

```
amount:10,cycle:400
amount:20,cycle:300
amount:30,cycle:500
new Dataset:

totalcount:20000--new row
amount:10,cycle:400
amount:20,cycle:300
amount:30,cycle:500
```

Comment: answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36926856/spark-sql-how-to-append-new-row-to-dataframe-table-from-another-table?rq=1

Comment: This link adds new columns ? I want to add something like a string to the start of the dataset

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36926856/2129801). The other question explicity asks for additional fields and targets to an SQL based solution (although the accepted answer does not use SQL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datasets are immutable, so you cannot add anything. But you can create a new dataset with the same schema that contains the new row(s) and then create a third dataset that is a of the old and the new one.

```scala
val originalDf = Seq("name: ABC",
  "class: 10",
  "name: ABC1",
  "class: 101",
  "name: ABCw",
  "class: 1019387",
  "name: ABCjdgewk",
  "class: 10118279").toDF()

val newRow = Seq("new row comes here").toDF()

val result = newRow.union(originalDf)
result.show()
```

prints

```
+------------------+
|             value|
+------------------+
|new row comes here|
|         name: ABC|
|         class: 10|
|        name: ABC1|
|        class: 101|
|        name: ABCw|
|    class: 1019387|
|   name: ABCjdgewk|
|   class: 10118279|
+------------------+
```

Ordering looks easy when you have only a small amount of data that fits on one of your executors (like in this example). If the data is distributed in a cluster, it is often not clear what is meant with *ordered*. Most Spark transformations do not keep an order within the data.

Comment: ordering.......

Comment: How to write val newRow = Seq("new row comes here").toDF()
in java

Comment: `Dataset<String> newRow = spark.createDataset(Arrays.asList("new row comes here"), Encoders.STRING());`

Comment: not really answer in my view as you allude to yourself...

Comment: @thebluephantom what would you recommend?

Comment: in this context ok, but if used down stream no real easy way. You need to add sequencing and a field that has original or added. Of course Spark is not really about sequential processing unless with a grouping key, which I am sure you r aware of.